# Alexa Dialog Flow Issue - Changing dialog course depending on question

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm new on this ASK development and I stuck on something (that's probably simple, but I could not find an answer yet):

My skill is related to home bread-making so, it has an intent with a series of questions, which the user will answer and then it will create a number of reminders, to alert the user through the whole baking process.

For all these questions the user needs to answer with a duration.
Alexa prompts an elicitation for each step so the user answers and it will fill the slot with the data. But, for one specific question, Alexa needs to ask the user if he will do that step, because it is optional, like the example below

> - Alexa: 'What is the interval between folds on your dough?'
> - User: '30 minutes'
> - Alexa: 'Are you going to let the dough ferment before the shape?'
> - User: 'Yes/No'
> - Alexa: If YES: 'Ok, for how long?'
>          If NO: 'Ok, skipping to the next step'

And after that, Alexa continues asking more questions to the user, until all slots are filled and it creates all the reminders...

What's the best approach? Do I need to create different intents or its ability to change the course of the dialog depending on this yes/no answer?

Anyone has already had this problem?

Thanks in advance to all!